# Association function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Users`, `Hosts`, and `Checkins`.

```
Users -> has_many -> Hosts -> has_many -> Checkins

Checkin -> belongs_to -> Host -> belongs_to -> User
```

How can I easily do a query for all checkins for a particular user without writing my own SQL?

Comment: I read that as 'chickens' with an accent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `has_many :through` association, like this:

```
has_many :checkins, :through => :hosts
```

You can then simply use `checkins` as your direct association. Whoo hoo!

Comment: I already tried that yesterday with no luck...I must have the wrong name for a key...I will investigate and update this with my results.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it worked fine this time.  I think maybe because I had just switched from webbrick to passenger/apache2 and maybe some old code was cached? I haven't read up yet on when (if ever) apache reloads changes without restarting the service.  Thanks again.